# what is the reason for considering two different variables holding same value equal

Tags: javascript

I might be terribly wrong but i needed to ask this question as it is confusing me and i suppose it is a very fundamental javascript question.

All my life I've been accustomed to the fact that variable names are pointer to the memeory location where the values are stored. Guess what

```
var a = 30
```

a is a pointer, pointing to the the memory location where 30 is stored. If we declare another variable, say

```
var b = 30
```

b will be another variable. And 30 will be stored somewhere in the memory and variable name 'b' will be used to lookup the value in the memory.

My point is, a and b are two different variable pointing two different memory location but two similar value.Then how come the following expression evaluates to true ? Why and what's the benefit for this kind of evaluation ?

```
a === b // true
```

Comment: `===` compares values

Comment: `===` compares values and their type @MinusFour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often a source of confusion in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, all values are passed and compared ***"by value"***. The issue is that variables that hold  primitives store the actual value of the primitive and variables that hold objects store the value of the memory location of the object.

Discussions about `==` vs. `===` are not relevant here as they both always compare values (values of the primitives or values of the memory locations), it's just that `===` doesn't do any implicit conversion of an operand's value before the comparison like `==` does. But, both always check a value against a value.

`30` is a primitive **value**. When comparing against it, the value of the primitive (not the memory location) will be compared.

Now, if you were to compare Objects, then the memory locations of those objects are what gets stored in the variable and that is what gets compared.

```js
// Primitive values (numbers, strings, booleans) are stored directly in variables
var a = 30; // 30 is a primitive value
var b = 30  // 30 is a primitive value

console.log(a === b)  // true because 30 === 30


// Object references (memory location) are stored in variables
var objA = {};
var objB = {};

console.log(objA === objB);  // False because the two variables store memory locations
```

FYI: If you were interested to know if two objects were essentially the same (not the same single instance in memory, but the same in terms of state), you could covert each into a primitive and then check those primitive values against each other:

```js
// Object references (memory location) are stored in variables
var objA = {
  x: "test",
  y: function(){ alert("Hi"); }
};

var objB = {
  x: "test",
  y: function(){ alert("Hi"); }
};

var objC = {
  x: "test",
  y: function(){ alert("HI"); }
};

// Stringify the object using a replacer function that will explicitly
// turn functions into strings so they won't be skipped like regular
// JSON.stringify() does
function stringifyAllMembers(obj) {
   return retVal = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, val) {
        return (typeof val === 'function') ? '' + val : val;
   });  
}

// Get the string primitive value of each object
var a = stringifyAllMembers(objA);
var b = stringifyAllMembers(objB);
var c = stringifyAllMembers(objC);

// Compare each primitive to compare each object:
console.log(a === b);  // true 
console.log(a === c);  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Strict Equality Comparison (===)  which in your case compare values (primitives) and not their memory location:

> Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is
>   implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the
>   values have different types, the values are considered unequal.
>   Otherwise, if the values have the same type and are not numbers,
>   they're considered equal if they have the same value. Finally, if both
>   values are numbers, they're considered equal if they're both not NaN
>   and are the same value, or if one is +0 and one is -0. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: Strict equality isn't the issue here. `a == b` also is `true`. The issue is that `30` is a primitive and variables store primitives directly (not memory locations as is the case with Objects).

Comment: Given only this explanation, you might think `[1, 2, 3] === [1, 2, 3]` is true.

Comment: This is not the answer to the OPs question. Both strict equality and equality with conversion compare values (value of a primitive or value of memory location). It's just that strict equality does a comparison without any type conversions on the operands first. –

Answer (score 0):

When you compare Numbers in javascript you are comparing values, and not references. That's why in your example a === b is true.
The way you think equality work is true for objects though, so lets say

```
var a = {
    x: 30
}

var b = {
    x: 30
}

a === b // false
```

Even though they appear the same

Answer (score -1):

In objects oriented languages, if a and b are objects, `a == b` is done by calling a.equals(b). And equals() compare some primitive types stored in private members. So, a and b can be two distinct instances of a class and be equal.

Comment: JavaScript does not have an `equals()` object method like many other OO languages do.

Comment: @Scott: the example in the question has been written in JavaScript, but the question was more general: the question finally says *a and b are two different variable pointing two different memory location*, so it does not only focus on JavaScript, for the reason that this sentense has no sense in JavaScript. So my answer was a general answer to a general question.

Comment: The question was tagged with `JavaScript` and all answers would be expected to relate to JavaScript. Since JavaScript operates very differently from most other OO languages, it is not appropriate to give general answers to JavaScript questions.

Comment: *The question was tagged with JavaScript and all answers would be expected to relate to JavaScript*?! the SO rules for a good answer do not say that a general answer is worst than a specific one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: But common sense does. *"In objects oriented languages, if a and b are objects, a == b is done by calling a.equals(b)."* is not a true statement.

Comment: Common sense is the answer when you have no answer: personnally, I prefer facts, instead of opinions, but it's only my opinion, not yours. Have a nice day.

Comment: If you prefer facts, why did your first sentence provide a statement that was untrue?

Comment: I did not answer your first question about my first sentence because I replied before you changed your answer to add this question: this is called a race condition, and this happened because you have changed your question. This is a fact.

Comment: @Scott: about my first sentence, again, instead of giving your opinion, you can give facts to explain **why** it is wrong. Please, do not have fear to give facts. I understand It is always very easy to criticize and more difficult to be constructive, but trust me, and this is a fact, it is much more interresting to try to do things. Some times.

Comment: There's no need to get all defensive and try to throw blame back at me. I just gave you a fair criticism of your answer. Stack Overflow is knowledge base. We want answers to be clear and accurate, not just for the OP, but for future visitors as well. Just read my answer and you'll have all the information you need.

Comment: @Scott: I thought it was common sense and good behaviour not to downvote an answer to a question you have also given an answer to. Because you should not be both judge and defendant. But as you like.

Comment: I don't know why or where you got that idea. There is no such rule or etiquette. We all strive for good answers and good comments wherever we can.

Comment: This idea is sometimes called *common sense*.

Comment: Well, I'll just say that your idea of common sense is contrary to the vast majority of people using Stack Overflow. Good luck.

Comment: **vast majority of people using Stack Overflow**: thanks for speaking for the community!

Comment: I think a member who's been here for over 6 years with over 20k rep can better speak for the community than someone who has been here for 55 days. How about you try to learn about the community you are now a part of before telling others how you think the site should run?

Comment: I've never talked in place of the community, I only talk on my own. **You** do that for the beginning of this talk. I do not see why having joined a community for less time than you make my answers about technical questions on programming wrong. May I've started programming before you. But this is not interresting, facts and ideas are. Not medals.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, because it is wrong. Has nothing to do with time spent here. You are conflating the discussion about your answer's merits and the etiquette of down voting because you just don't like that your answer got down voted. Stack Overflow is about quality information. Your answer is not that. Good luck.

Comment: @Scott: saying **Your answer is wrong, because it is wrong** is a total nonsense. If an answer is wrong, it may certainly be explained why.

Comment: And, as I have said repeatedly, read my answer for all the information you need.

Comment: I've already read your really nice answer for some minutes (instead of reading your profile).

Comment: Great! Then, you have everything you have been asking for. Goodbye and good luck!